# Is this assembly code generated complete?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, assembly

I wrote this simple C code and compiled it using Visual Studio 2010, with assembler output.

```
int main(){
    int x=1;
    int y=2;
    int z=x+y;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the assembly output..

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 

    TITLE   foobar.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

EXTRN   @__security_check_cookie@4:PROC
PUBLIC  _main
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
; File foobar.cpp
;   COMDAT _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 2    :    int x=1;
; 3    :    int y=2;
; 4    :    int z=x+y;
; 5    :    return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 6    : }

    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Is this complete? I do not see any `ADD` statement. What compiler can be used to compile it?

Comment: Change "return 0;"  to "return z+x+y;"  and have another look at the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your code doesn't *do* anything with those values, the compiler has optimized most of it out. As Carl mentioned, all that remains is the `xor eax, eax` which is zeroing eax,  the register that the return value is placed.

Even if you were to `printf("%d", z)`, your result `z` is a compile-time constant (3), and that is all you would see in the assembly listing.

What you can do is disable optimizations in your project C++ properties, and you should see your expected assembly. Also, building in Release mode should minimize the extra debug stuff you see in the asm.

Comment: In fact it's optimized out everything except the `return 0`.

Comment: Wow.. that was a quick one. Thanks.

Comment: I see the code explicitly returning 0(ret 0).. why zeroing EAX?

Comment: For nearly all function calling conventions on x86, the return value is in eax. `ret 0` does not mean "return zero". It means return, and clear 0 bytes from the stack frame.

Comment: if you want to see the asm code for the addition, you have two choices: either add something that makes the inputs variable (e.g. read it with scanf, or you could declare the variables volatilie) and use the output (e.g. printf the result or return the result of the addition). The other way would be to disable all code optimizations.